# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_child'

Tags: python, folium

I have few `feature groups` created for folium as follows

```
feature_group_1 = folium.FeatureGroup('1').add_to(m)
feature_group_2 = folium.FeatureGroup('2').add_to(m)
feature_group_3 = folium.FeatureGroup('3').add_to(m)
feature_group_4 = folium.FeatureGroup('4').add_to(m)
```

I am adding few data to the map and adding to the `feature group`, instead of sending them to the `feature group` directly i am picking the `feature group` based on the data from `if loop` and storing them in a variable `fg` when i use the below code and try to add the entry to `feature group`

```
for Numbers,Names,latitude,longitude in zip(bef['Numbers'],bef['Names'],bef['latitude'],bef['longitude']):
if Name=='Jon':
    fg=str("feature_group_"+Numbers)
    folium.Marker(location=[latitude,longitude],
              icon=folium.DivIcon(html=f"""<div style="font-family: {'courier new'}; font-size: {'24pt'}; font-weight: {'bold'}; color: {'Purple'}">{Names}</div>""")                          
              ).add_to(fg)
```

i am getting the below error

```
 File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 113, in add_to
    parent.add_child(self, name=name, index=index)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_child'
```

what needs to be done to fix this

Comment: What happens if you replace `fg=str("feature_group_"+Number)` with `fg = locals()["feature_group_"+Number]` ?

Comment: oh my god, you genius , nailed it, its working perfectly fine.. is it on the doc somewhere? please add this as answer

Comment: This can be made more more clear and explicit -- I would not recommend using/indexing locals.

Comment: @SeanPianka:  I agree.  I only asked to make sure the root issue was what I thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

`folium.Marker.add_to` does not accept arguments of type `str`, so you must pass the correct object to it. Specifically, the argument should be of type `folium.Map`.

Comment: How can i choose a feature group based on a condition then?

Comment: Don't create separate `feature_group_#` variables: create a `feature_groups` list, put each feature group as an element of this list, and index into the list to retrieve the desired feature_group.